# Oracle Number issue on 18c vs 19c

Tags: oracle, numbers, sqldatatypes, oracle18c, oracle19c

Need a confirmation on this below behavior of NUMBER Datatype on both the Oracle versions(**18c vs 19c**),

In 18c,

```sql
select cast(0.003856214813393653 as number(20,18)) from dual;
```

--output

```
0.00385621481339365
```

In 19c,

```sql
select cast(0.003856214813393653 as number(20,18)) from dual;
```

--output

```
0.003856214813393653
```

Why does the truncation of last digit happen for 18c?

Is this an issue with version?

Plus 18c seems to to be unable to handle scale values more than 17.

Comment: Cannot replicate your output on Oracle 18c [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=05ae81b9e81295160ece49de33b4fb96)

Comment: I also don't get the asserted out on my 18c XE instance. Are you sure this is not a client display issue?

Comment: Which tool are you using to execute query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to Oracle / PLSQL developer tool setting issue. please try with the below options to resolve the same

> Tools -> Preferences -> SQL Window -> Number fields to_char

Answer (score 0):

This is at the whim of the *client* settings not the database. For example, I ran all of these on the same database

```
SQL Plus
========
SQL> select cast(0.003856214813393653 as number(20,18)) from dual;

CAST(0.003856214813393653ASNUMBER(20,18))
-----------------------------------------
                               .003856215

SQL Developer
=============
select cast(0.003856214813393653 as number(20,18)) from dual;

0.003856214813393653

SQLcl
======
SQL> select cast(0.003856214813393653 as number(20,18)) from dual;

CAST(0.003856214813393653ASNUMBER(20,18))
-----------------------------------------
                             .00385621481
```

The client tool decides on the precision to show